# Traer datos de la tabla mediante un ID

Tags: php, sql

por favor necesito su ayuda con esto. Tengo esta tabla en la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que en la columna ID me aparezca una lista para seleccionar los IDs que tengo en esta base de datos, y al seleccionar un ID me cargue el artículo y el precio unidad en la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que quieres es un `<select>` con `<options>` de los id que tiene o como?

Comment: @matahombres si, la idea seria que mediante un select me aparezcan los ids que tengo en la tabla de la base de datos (en este caso serian los 3 que tengo en la tabla), y luego al elegir ese id en el select, me cargue el articulo y el precioUnidad en la vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Planteamiento:** Los options los creas con una llamada a la base de datos de php. La idea es añadir una clase con el id a los elementos correspondientes de esa forma cuando le das click muestras los `<td>` correspondiente clase id. Luego ejecutamos un script (utilizaré JQuery ya que es más sencillo) que cuando le de click al select muestre con un `show();`

**Codigo:**

```
<select id="seletp">
   <?php while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ ?>
         <option value="<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["id"];?></option>
   <?php 
     }
   ?>
</select>
<table id="tablel">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>Articulo</td>
   <td>Precio/Unidad</td>
   <td>Cantidad</td>
   <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <?php while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ ?>
         <td class="ej consulta-<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["id"];?></td>
         <td class="ej consulta-<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["articulo"];?></td>
         <td class="ej consulta-<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["precioUnidad"];?></td>
         <td class="ej consulta-<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["cantidad"];?></td>
   <?php 
     }
   ?>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ej").hide();
  $("#seletp").click(function(){
    var id=$("#seletp").val();
    var clase="consulta-"+id;
    $(".ej").hide();
    $("#tablel").find(clase).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: no me muestra nada, que consulta deberia hacer a la db?

Answer (score 0):

@matahombres esto es todo lo que me muestra : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

te dejo el código

```
<?php
    // Ejemplo de conexión a base de datos MySQL con PHP.
    //
    // Ejemplo realizado por Oscar Abad Folgueira: http://www.oscarabadfolgueira.com y https://www.dinapyme.com

    // Datos de la base de datos
    $usuario = "root";
    $password = "";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "sistfacturacion";

    // creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

    // Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
    // establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
    $fila = "SELECT id,articulo,precioUnidad FROM factura2";
    $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $fila ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

    ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="seletp">
   <?php while($fila=mysqli_feth_array($resultado)){ ?>
         <option value="<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["id"];?></option>
   <?php 
     }
   ?>
</select>
<table id="tablel">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>Articulo</td>
   <td>Precio/Unidad</td>
   <td>Cantidad</td>
   <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <?php while($fila=mysqli_feth_array($resultado)){ ?>
         <td class="ej consulta-<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["id"];?></td>
         <td class="ej consulta-<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["articulo"];?></td>
         <td class="ej consulta-<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["precioUnidad"];?></td>
         <td class="ej consulta-<?= $fila["id"];?>"><?= $fila["cantidad"];?></td>
   <?php 
     }
   ?>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>


    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ej").hide();
  $("#seletp").click(function(){
    var id=$("#seletp").val();
    var clase="consulta-"+id;
    $(".ej").hide();
    $("#tablel").find(clase).show();
  });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>


<?php 


    mysqli_close( $conexion );


 ?>
```

en donde crees que esta el problema?

Comment: Mm... haz un echo a `mysqli_num_rows($resultado);` a ver que te sale. Te muestra cuantas filas tiene la consulta

Comment: me da como resultado 4, y esta bien, son las 4 filas que tengo en la tabla de la db

Comment: lo que no se es porque no me muestra nada.. ni siquiera las tablas html :S

Comment: A veces los errores los pone en el F12 cuando inspeccionas un elmento, comprueba a ver si tiene algún error

Comment: bueno el problema era de sintaxis, estaba "mysqli_feth_array" en vez de "mysqli_fetch_array"

Comment: Oh... Mi culpa :S. He corregido el post también por si algún otro usuario le sirve de algo :S

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86689/discussion-between-david-bucci-and-matahombres).